# Как легко изменить поменять значение одной ссылки в html документе

Tags: html, url, ссылки

На моем сайте есть реферальная ссылка, используемая в нескольких местах.
Иногда возникает необходимость поменять url этой ссылки на всем сайте сразу.
Есть ли способ создать что-то вроде переменной с url ссылки в одном месте и потом в остальных местах сайта просто ссылаться на эту переменную?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, должна ли эта ссылка индексироваться. Если да, то вариант с переменной в JS не подходит. Лучше всего делать это в back end коде (C#, php и др.) вставляя переменную со ссылкой в нужное место сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас используется шаблонизатор, то достаточно определить переменную и периодически менять её значение при передаче в шаблонизатор. Но это грязный путь, я бы сделал отдельный модуль по генерации реферральных ссылок, чтобы все изменения происходили централизованно.

Или же можно при загрузке страницы запускать JavaScript, который будет ходить на сервер через AJAX, брать актуальную ссылку и проставлять её где нужно. Вам же не обязательно чтобы эта ссылка индексировалась посковиками.

На чем сайт написан?

Comment: У меня блог на блогспоте. Из программирования доступно только вставить javascript в шаблон.